# grails-CodeNarc and Service Stateless ruleSet

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, codenarc

I am trying  to use `codeNarc` on a grails project, after installing it and running it  I've have some rulesets violations messages that I would like to understand and resolve. The first on concern "GrailsStatelessService" and the second the  "equals() and  toString()" methods...

For the first one "GrailsStatelessService" the message  I received is:

```
***************************
Violation in class app.TheServiceName. The class is marked as stateless but contains the non-final field 'aVariableName'
***************************
```

I've searched a little about that but not found a lot of tricks about that. Can someone please explain me what the real meaning of this ruleset and what I have to do to solve this problem/

About the second kind of ruleSet I found somewhere that it solved by overriding those  methods in all the domain classes but is  hat an obligation, a need, or  do I just have to modify the ruleSet File to avoid those kinds of messages related to those rulesets?

And that introduces my last question: where to find  this ruleSet File( the default one within  codenarc) or the one i must include myself?

Answer (score 4):

I find that the `GrailsStatelessService` rule does sometimes catch a real violation, so rather than disabling it, I modify it to ignore my commonly used field names.

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
codenarc.propertiesFile = 'grails-app/conf/codenarc.properties'
```

codenarc.properties:

```
GrailsStatelessService.addToIgnoreFieldNames=grailsApplication,applicationContext,sessionFactory
```

Comment: Similarly, this worked for me for Grails 2.0 (in BuildConfig.groovy):  
`codenarc.properties = { `  
`GrailsPublicControllerMethod.enabled = false`  
`GrailsStatelessService.addToIgnoreFieldNames = 'grailsApplication,messageSource,*Dao'`  
`}`

Answer (score 3):

I am able to configure this CodeNarc rules as follows:

1. Install CodeNarc plugin [*grails install-plugin codenarc*]
2. Add following line in **BuildConfig.groovy** file [for details configuration]:

   ```
   codenarc.propertiesFile = 'grails-app/conf/codenarc.properties'
   ```
3. In ***codenarc.properties*** - file, I add following rule for ignore few RULEs

   ```
   codenarc.properties = {

     GrailsDomainHasEquals.enabled = false

     GrailsDomainHasToString.enabled = false

     EmptyMethod.enabled = false

   }
   ```
4. Run following command for generating CodeNarc Report: `grails codenarc`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes condenarc mix things ups. Adding Service at the end of the name of the service remove this "issue" if you are not using a class as stateless but codenarc believes so. I had this problem with this Service:

```
private CurrencyConverterFactory currencyConverterFactory
```

And I fixed with:

```
private CurrencyConverterFactory currencyConverterFactoryService
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rules-grails.html) does a good job of explaining that rule:

> Checks for non-final fields on a Grails service class. Grails service
>   classes are singletons by default, and so they should be reentrant. In
>   most cases, this implies (or at least encourages) that they should be
>   stateless.
>
> This rule ignores final fields (either instance or static). Fields
>   that are static and non-final, however, do cause a violation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **Grails CodeNarc plugin**, then see the plugin documentation for a list of the **CodeNarc** rulesets that are included by default. There is also a section on "Configuring The CodeNarc RuleSet File(s)" -- so by all means create your own custom ruleset.

http://www.grails.org/plugin/codenarc/

It is expected that you customize the set of rules appropriate for your team/project. Other than the "basic" rulset, the other provided rulesets all contain rules that may or may not be appropriate for you.

The **GrailsDomainHasToString** and **GrailsDomainHasEquals** rules are perfect examples -- many organizations disable those rules.

See the **CodeNarc** documentation for more information on turning off a rule:

http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-configuring-rules.html